# How to autoupdate an MS word field based on typed text?

Tags: ms-word, field, qr-code

Is there a way to automatically update the content of a word field based on a text I type?
i.e. I have a table with two cells. The left cell contains a QR Code generated by

```
{ Displaybarcode "Just a Text " QR \s 40 \t }
```

The rigtht cell contains "Just a text"

[image]

Is there a way to update the QR code (actually a word field) based on what I type in the right cell?

So, if I change the text to "I just changed that text!"
I would get this:
[image]

I do not mind pressing Ctrl-F9, but I would not want to edit the field itself.
Is that possible?

Dan

Comment: There is [some discussion about these fields here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/creating-barcode-or-qr-code-using-vba-from-data-in/6a037241-9845-4c6a-bc33-e12de9720a60). What properties can you read from the first field if you loop the range of the table (?) cell containing your code ?  If you can read from it, you can also change it.  You can probably do this using a VBA macro.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the area for the text in a [mapped Content Control](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/mapped_content_controls.html) and use a copy of that control in the DisplayBarCode field as the text portion. The field would need to be updated.

Here is [another Add-In to produce Mapped Content Controls](http://www.gmayor.com/insert_content_control_addin.htm) by MVP Graham Mayor.

Here is a [video by Laura Townsend](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OtFhIqK0gec) on how to do it yourself.

Here is the [Walkthrough page on mapping to an XML part from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-binding-content-controls-to-custom-xml-parts?view=vs-2019&tabs=vb).

Comment: Thanks. Very challenging for me. I do not understand half of it.
And by the way, the download of the Content Control Tools at the end of the page https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/content_control_tools.html triggered a Trojan Warning for me. See https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/476e9dcfe7e548a99c05453bfcfeee036cae5ef076711906b4e8d4377d78b033

Comment: @CharlesKenyon Luckily, the field does not even need to be updated using F9! (It has wdFieldKind = 1, i.e. Hot, like the EQ field and updates automatically whenever the text in it is modified, even when that's done via the Content Control replication mechanism. So all the user would need do is tab out of the Control.